# Android Studio - Showing missing methods in lower APIs

Tags: android, android-studio

Let us say that I have a project running on a minimum api level of 21. If I switch the minimum supported api level to 7, is there any way to make android studio show all of the function calls which are not supported on the api level 7 ?

Because right now I am pretty sure that my project has methods which are not supported in api level 7, but still android studio builds the gradle and does not give any errors.

I want to know the specific names of the methods, so I could implement them differently.

Comment: why dont you run lint?

Comment: Newbie to Android Studio, I was used with eclipse running it automatically.

Comment: Your comment solves my question, post an answer @gvsharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically you need to run  the lint..

In Android Studio, the configured lint and other IDE inspections run automatically whenever you compile your program. You can also manually run inspections in Android Studio by selecting Analyze > Inspect Code from the application or right-click menu. The Specify Inspections Scope dialog appears so you can specify the desired inspection profile and scope.

Comment: Analyze -> Inspect code does exactly what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In your build.gradle file you can find `compileSdkVersion` which is the version of the compiler used to build the app. If you'll decrease it to api level 7, your project wont compile while unsupported methods exists.